# TFS Power Tool (tfpt) update datetime field syntax

Tags: datetime, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I'm attempting to use Team Foundation Power Tools to update a custom datetime field and cannot seem to find the correct syntax.

**Context**

1. VS2013 with TFPT installed
2. TFS 2013 Update 4
3. I'm trying to do this through powershell

I've created a custom datetime field which I would like to set to a specific datetime. I **can** set other fields without issue, and the field  **is** a datetime type.

I have tried the commands using Xml datetime format, and my current locale (English US) and neither seem to be acceptable.

```
tfpt workitem /update 1890 /fields:"Test.Common.DeployDate=6/23/2015 07:30 PM" /collection:$collection
```

and

```
tfpt workitem /update 1890 /fields:"Test.Common.DeployDate=2015-06-23T00:00:00" /collection:$collection
```

In both cases I receive error TF237124: Work item is not ready to save.

Has anyone been able to set datetime fields this way, and if so what is the datetime format I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Use Get-date: `$line.'Date released'` has a value like 04/25/2015

```
$wi.Fields['myCo.yourDate'].Value = $( Get-date $line.'Date Released')
```

Hope that helps